# Product Quantity in configure product page whmcs

Tags: configuration, whmcs

Is there any way to add a field to enter the quantity of the product in configureproduct.tpl file ? Like the one in Cart page ? And I need the same using ajax. The Quantity provided in this new field should be updated in the cart page also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Configurable Option in WHMCS, there is quantity field.

- Open Configurable Options, from Setup > Products/Services.
- Add group for the product (Group of fields).
- Assign products to have this group of Configurable Options.
- Add Configurable Option and select type as Quantity.